# multiple calendars for multiple users in php

Tags: php, calendar, multi-user

I've been looking into lots of calendar scripts, but so far I haven't found one that offers - or could be easily modified that way - separate calendars for each user. More specific: The different users shouldn't share one calendar, each one has it's own. Everyone can modify his own calendar which is visible - read only - to every other user.

Functionality similiar to this:
http://demo.guestcal.com/admin/
Problem is that most calendars use several tables in a database, and I can't create thousands of separate databases. Separate table for each user in the same database would be fine.

Before programming it from scratch, I wonder if anyone knows a PHP script that comes close to these needs?

Comment: Code up a simple calendar display and store specific events for each user..?

Answer (score 0):

For different look and feel of can specify/create the different CSS files for the calendar. And save the each user settings in database.